# what is the difference between "VLIB_malloc" supported by TI Cx66 Vlib and c function "malloc"?

Tags: memory, signal-processing, alloc, code-composer

in the TI document it says " Following should be called to allocate buffers passed to VLIB functions for each test vector" before the define of "VLIB_malloc" function. can someone tell me what maybe the difference between VLIB_malloc and c function "malloc"?